# Django - Model too large?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create one large model with 270 model fields, it were originally nested jsons, but when it comes to .filter() it turned out that json paths (e.g. myjsonfoo__0__myjsonkey__gte filter) are pretty pretty slow. So I decided to either

- split it into 6 models with 1 parent (option 1)
- keep all together inside one model (270 model fields, option 2).

What would you suggest? is it too heavy to manage 270 modelfields? (small production database, postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

The choice largely hinges on your specific database, with relational databases often proving less optimal for this scenario, favoring the use of wide column databases instead. There are two primary approaches to structuring your models: Firstly, consider employing an abstract-based model that introduces no disruptions to your existing table. Also, you can opt for multi-table inheritance, which involves separating your tables and establishing relations between them. In this context, if you prefer not to retrieve data from all tables simultaneously, the performance is enhanced. However, if your objective is to fetch data from all tables, it introduces additional joins to your query, potentially slowing down the process.

To enhance the speed of your table, another option is to consider adding an index. Please note that this suggestion is somewhat speculative as I currently lack information about the size of your table.

Comment: Hi thanks. My current table is: 1 GB RAM / 1vCPU / 10 GB Disk - PostgreSQL 15. And my latest plan is to have a parent model with 6 child models (each holds ca. 37 model fields) pointing at the parent. So I assume that we will have 10 000 * 7 instances where 60 000 instances of them feed the 37*6 = 222 modefields having a total of 13.320.000 model field entries (Mixin of char, decimal, bigintegerfields). Would you estimate problems with annotations/filtering/statistics on any/multiple fields with these numbers? Thanks

Comment: The optimization strategy entirely on the nature of your data and the specific queries you are running. A thorough analysis of both is crucial, guiding you to implement necessary adjustments to your tables or models accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create one large model with 270 model fields,

You almost certainly don't want to do this. I don't say there isn't any case ever where this might be necessary, but you almost certainly don't need to.

Look at the data and analyse it, then think about how to design models.

Is there a choices field for example, where the value of that field means certain other fields are not used (i.e. you have fields that only exist for specific choices) - look at different models for each choice.

Is there unstructured data in there that you're trying to handle? Don't do it with named fields becasue if the incoming data changes your model is broken. Use JSON fields. If you need to validate the structure for a specific data field define a dataclass and write a serializer for that field.

Consider parent/child models where necesaary and add indexes for performance (you don't say whether you are mainly read, or if it's heavy writes as well - that could make a difference to design).

Basically, you need to spend time on analysing the data itself, the reasons you need it, the processes that need to read and write it. Without doing this, there is no "catch all" solution that will help you here.

Comment: Hi, thanks. So I tended to use jsonfields for this purpose as I mentioned. However I'd like to use a different approach now to perform filter() and statistic queries. E.g. when I had a  jsonfield that holds 37 * 500 json keys inside the array, it can't perform good. So I think I will break it down into 6 * 37 modelfields (6 models) with a FK to a parent model. It is a mixin of read/writing, once it is written it wont change (fixed data).  I will try my best to break things down.

Comment: My main point is that you shouln't just do random stuff until something seems to work. You need to understand all the requriements behind this data to know the best way to structure it. This is a fair sized task, and not just a "shove it all in a model" part of coding something. For some people this sort of thing is an entire job.